# Django breaking after adding extend and load static tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

so I used template inheritance in django. After I used

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}
{% load static %}
```

the html and css doesnt update. What I mean by that if for example when I change the page title then save and refresh [both by ctrl f5 and ctrl r] it doesnt do anything. The extending works fine but when I use load static first of all it doesn't load it second when I update or add any html its like "I dont care" and doesnt update anything.
The code

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Do</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Help </p>    
</body>
</html>
```

basic.html

```
<div class="upper">
<p class="blogtitle"> Utsab's Blogs </p>
<a href="/" class="homebutton"> Home </a>
<a href="blogs" class="blogsbutton"> Blogs </a>
<a href="contact" class="contactbutton"> Contact </a>
</div>


<style>
.upper{
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}

.blogtitle {
    text-align: center;

}
.name {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: larger;
}
.text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
}
.homebutton {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 29%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: azure;
}
.blogsbutton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 48%;
    top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: azure;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.contactbutton {
    left: 68%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: azure;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.homebutton:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
.blogsbutton:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
.contactbutton:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Comment: will basic.html be inside body tag?

Comment: sorry what? i dont get it

Comment: no basic.html is not inside the body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the `basic.html` not `extends`.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Do</title>
</head>
<body>
{% include "basic.html" %}
    <p> Help </p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/) carefully.